# methods to split an array other than odd/even

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, algorithm, sorting

this is 
I have user posts and I want to split them into 3 but all what comes in mind is odd/even like this :

```
@Post1 = Post.where('post_id % 2 = 0')
@post2 = Post.where('post_id % 2 != 0')
```

is there a way to add `@post3` and split posts into 3 categories. this is for research purposes and thanks ..

Comment: How about `Post.all.in_groups_of(Post.count / 3)`? Besides the obvious, `post_id % 3 = 2`, etc...

Comment: thanks @Phlip for participating  but I am trying to make 3 variables to use them in the view "@post1'  '@post2'  '@post3' so that i can call them in my view and in_groups_of only applies at one variable and I didn't get "Besides the obvious, post_id % 3 = 2"

Comment: @keith You need to look up what % does.  It should be very obvious how you'd use %3 to break it into 3 groups if you're already using %2 to break it into 2.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I know it means dividable and returns the result of division but I looked for the hardest way to do it instead of the simpleset out there : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@Post1 = Post.where('post_id % 3 = 0')
@post2 = Post.where('post_id % 3 = 1')
@post3 = Post.where('post_id % 3 = 2')
```

It's the same approach as even/odd. 
The % operator returns the mod of division, so you can extend it to any number you want. Anyway, don't think it's a good way to do that, specially if your number of sets is too high. I would suggest to use `in_groups_of` (https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) method.

In your case, you could use in_groups_of like this:

```
@posts = Post.all.in_groups_of((Post.count.to_f/3).ceil, false)
```

Like that, you can assign it like this:

```
@Post1 = @posts[0]
@post2 = @posts[1]
@post3 = @posts[2]
```

or, what I think would be way much better, is only assign your @posts variable. Then, on your view, you iterate over it like this:

```
- @posts.each do |group_of_posts|
  - group_of_posts.each do |post|
    # do whatever you want
```

Like that, your code keeps way much cleaner and easier to maintain. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for answering @Ronan Lopes but how can I use in_groups_of in my case and thanks alot

Comment: just a minute and I'll update the answer showing you how

Comment: Thanks alot mr @Ronan Lopes this  worked perfectly . . .